# Algorithm for creating realistic flying (voxel) islands

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources, extreme-terrain, video-games, algorithms

I am currently working on a part of a game that has **voxel-based terrain**, a bit like Minecraft. There are different kinds of „blocks“ like stone, dirt, sand, etc. But the story/setting requires that I write a generator that creates **flying islands**.
So naturally I did some research about terrain generation (of islands). I also specifically looked at Minecraft‘s terrain generation algorithm. The problem: All the methods I found use (higher dimensional) noise and transform it somehow to build up the terrain. This is done sometimes because it allows seamless terrain, but mostly for performance reasons. The downside is that the generated worlds contain artifacts and many places that just feel unrealistic.

I don‘t really care about performance; the generation process is running upfront and the resulting terrain will be modified and exported as a finished piece. What I do care about is that my islands look and feel absolutely fantastic. I want that things make sense, like a river flowing from a glacier to the edge of the island (where it will form a giant waterfall), smoothly following the terrain on the way. And not like in Minecraft, where a river will happily fall down a giant cliff and then stop because it‘s blocked by a single piece of bamboo.

In addition, I found it particularly hard to find or figure out an algorithm for the size of my islands. It‘s relatively easy to create a whole continent or a little „Cast Away“ island, but I want my islands to have a diameter between 10‘000 and 20‘000 blocks, which is large enough to promote exploration but still small enough for isolation.

**My question is:** How would you guys tackle this problem? What kind of algorithms would you use? And how would you tune them to support the maximum amount of diversity (like glaciers, desserts, caves, etc.)?

I don‘t want or expect a finished solution here. But I would appreciate any idea you guys have that might point me into the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: These seem like technical problems related to game development, unrelated to creating a fictional world.

Comment: Suddenly remembered we have a [gamedev.se] site on the network. When you arrive, please take their tour, read their help centre etc..

Comment: Extending what Jiminy Cricket said, I fear looking for algorithm ideas and something "beautiful and fantastic" won't give enough details and goals about your problem, both here and Game dev. It would have been easier if you already have an algorithm, but you're not sure how to change it to reach your goals, or better, how to fix a bug you see in it :/.